# How to pass 2 parameters and return the third parameter of Closest Object

Tags: javascript

I can't make a method that takes 2 parameters (latitude and longitude) and returns the nearest city to the entered values. 
I made a method to find the closest in longitude(findNearestLongitudeCity) and I made a method to find the closest in latitude(findNearestLatitudeCity). But it doesn’t work out to make a method that will return 1 city closest to the two entered values ​​of longitude and latitude. (Method findNearestCity doesn't work it's always returned Atlanta).
Please help me to do that Method. If u need all conditions you can see them after the code.

```
function CityMap(str) {
    function CityMapRecording(str) {
        [this.city, this.latitude, this.longitude] = str.split(" ,");
    }
    this.list = [];
    str.split(";").forEach(row => {
        this.list.push(new CityMapRecording(row));
    });
}

CityMap.prototype.findNearestLatitudeCity = function (i) {
    return this.list.filter(function (x) {
        return x.latitude >= i || x.latitude <= i;
    }).sort(function (x, y) {
        return Math.abs(x.latitude - i) - Math.abs(y.latitude - i);
    })[0];
}
CityMap.prototype.findNearestLongitudeCity = function (j) {
    return this.list.filter(function (k) {
        return k.longitude >= j || k.longitude <= j;
    }).sort(function (k, l) {
        return Math.abs(k.longitude - j) - Math.abs(l.longitude - j);
    })[0];
}
CityMap.prototype.findNearestCity = function (j, x) {
    return this.list.filter(function (k) {
        return k.longitude >= j || k.longitude <= j && k.latitude >=x || k.latitude <=x;
    }).sort(function (k, l) {
        return Math.abs(k.longitude - j) - Math.abs(l.longitude - j) && Math.abs(k.latitude - x) - Math.abs(l.latitude - x);
    })[0];
}
var objCityMap = new CityMap("Nashville, TN ,36.17 ,-86.78;New York, NY ,40.71 ,-74.00;Atlanta, GA ,33.75 ,-84.39;Denver, CO ,39.74 ,-104.98;Seattle, WA ,47.61 ,-122.33;Los Angeles, CA ,34.05 ,-118.24;Memphis, TN , 35.15 ,-90.05");
console.log(objCityMap.list);
console.log(objCityMap.findNearestLatitudeCity(35.15).city)
console.log(objCityMap.findNearestLongitudeCity(-86).city)
console.log(objCityMap.findNearestCity(42, -122).city)
```

all conditions: (Define a new object called ‘CityMap’ that can be instantiated with ‘new’, using its constructor. The constructor takes one parameter as a string - this list of cities and their latitudes and longitudes:   "Nashville, TN", 36.17, -86.78; "New York, NY", 40.71, -74.00; "Atlanta, GA", 33.75, -84.39 etc. This ‘CityMap’ object should have the following method: Pass longitude and latitude as parameters, and return the name of the city that is closest to that location)

Comment: <search provider of your choice> -> _"javascript nearest location longitude latitude"_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thing is, latitude and longitude difference can't just be calculated as simple subtraction to get the distance

There is a well known formula to calculate the distance between 2 coordinates, which I copied from [here](https://www.geodatasource.com/developers/javascript)

```
function distance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2, unit) {
    if ((lat1 == lat2) && (lon1 == lon2)) {
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        var radlat1 = Math.PI * lat1/180;
        var radlat2 = Math.PI * lat2/180;
        var theta = lon1-lon2;
        var radtheta = Math.PI * theta/180;
        var dist = Math.sin(radlat1) * Math.sin(radlat2) + Math.cos(radlat1) * Math.cos(radlat2) * Math.cos(radtheta);
        if (dist > 1) {
            dist = 1;
        }
        dist = Math.acos(dist);
        dist = dist * 180/Math.PI;
        dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515;
        if (unit=="K") { dist = dist * 1.609344 }
        if (unit=="N") { dist = dist * 0.8684 }
        return dist;
    }
}
```

You can use this formula to add `distance` field in your list using `map` in the first operation & then `sort` the list by `distance` in the second operation & then get the first element which will be the closest city to given coordinates

Like this,

```
CityMap.prototype.findNearestCity = function (lat, lan) {
    return this.list.map(function (k) {
        k.distance = distance(k.latitude,k.longitude,lat,lan);
        return k;
    }).sort(function (k, l) {
        return k.distance < l.distance ? -1 : 1;
    })[0];
}
```